# Does SpringData Couchbase provide any way to get realtime events?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have a question related to Couchbase eventing. In Firebase/Firestore DB you can use a nice feature where you can be registered through the API to be notified when for example a new document is created or updated. I need to do the same thing with Couchbase but the Couchbase Event system is more like the old PLSQL or similar language to trigger some actions between DB objects and executing some action according to that, but I want a more reactive/real-time approach using Java SDK.

Do you know if is it possible to do that with just Couchbase (something like a listener without curl function)?

Also, I tried to do a test with SpringDataCouchbase using a simple findAll. That operation returns a Flux but it's a finite flux that finishes when all items are retrieved.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for Couchbase as a product manager for the Eventing service.

If you've already evaluated the Eventing service and decided it doesn't meet your requirements, I would direct you to a similar topic  [How to capture save or update events in Couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844314/how-to-capture-save-or-update-events-in-couchbase)

Note, we are actively working on adding a developer preview feature to Eventing similar to Amazon's Simple Queue Service to the next major Couchbase release.

Comment: That would be great for my requirement. Thx @Jon Strabala.